# Provide parameters from other Jenkins projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Say, I have 2 Jenkins-Jobs (it might get more) A and B. I am unsing Jenkins version 2.138.2.

A has 2 parameters:

- param_name1: Selection
- param_name2: Git Parameter

B has also 2 parameters:

- param_name1: Selection (same as A)
- param_name3: Git Parameter (different to A, both in naming and Git Repository)

I would like to have another job C, which provides all parameters from job A and B; thus job C should dynamically provide 3 parameters.

Is there any plugin, which provides this feature? Or is there any other working way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know such a plugin. But you can do it by yourself. I would recommend to create a [global shared lib](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#extending-with-shared-libraries) and than define a method **getMyParameters**, with the file *vars/getMyParameters.groovy* as follow:

```
def call(Map config)
{ 
   boolean isA = config["isA"]
   boolean isB = config["isB"]
   boolean isC = config["isC"]
   def propertiesList = []
   if(isA || isB || isC)
   {
      propertiesList << choice(choices: ['a', 'b', 'c'], description: 'my param_name1', name: 'param_name1')
   }
   if(isA || isC)
   {
      propertiesList << string(defaultValue: '-', description: 'my param_name2', name: 'param_name2', trim: false)
   }
   if(isB || isC)
   {
      propertiesList << string(defaultValue: '-', description: 'my param_name3', name: 'param_name2', trim: false)
   }
   return propertiesList
}
```

Now you can reuse the parameters in your Jenkinsfiles like:

```
@Library('my-jenkins-shared-lib@master')  _

properties([parameters(getMyParameters(isA: true, isB: false, isC: false))])

pipeline 
{
    agent none

    stages
    {
        stage("JobA")
        {
            steps
            {
                echo 'Hello JobA'
            }
        }
    }
}
```